# Error al subir imagen en PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de crear un sistema de novedades y en cada novedad tiene que ir una imagen, lo que estoy haciendo es esto:

```
<?php

    $user = 1;
    $fecha = date('d/m/Y');
    $act = 1;

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = 'img/'.$image;
    copy($ruta, $destino);

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['contenido']) && !empty($_POST['image'])){
            $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO novedades (userid, imagen, titulo, contenido, fecha, act) VALUES (:us, :img, :tit, :cont, :d, :ac)");
            $add->bindValue(':us', $user);
            $add->bindValue(':img', $destino);
            $add->bindValue(':tit', $_POST['titulo']);
            $add->bindValue(':cont', $_POST['contenido']);
            $add->bindValue(':d', $fecha);
            $add->bindValue(':ac', $act);
            $add->execute();
            header('location: ../');
        }else {
            echo 'Campos incompletos. Vuelva a intentarlo';
        }
    }

?>
```

Formulario

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea style="height: 240px;" name="contenido" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Seleccione una imagen</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
    </div>

    <button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

El problema es que la imagen no sube a la carpeta `img` y en la base de datos solo guarda la carpeta de destino que es `img`. No se donde esta el error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- La codificación del formulario debe ser `enctype="multipart/form-data"` cuando se desea subir una imagen

2- Debes asegurarte que el directorio donde subes la imagen tiene permiso de escritura por parte del usuario del servidor web (el usuario es www-data si usas linux) y la ruta la puedes dar en forma absoluta para no equivocarte por ejemplo en mi caso la subiré a `/var/www/html` que es un directorio de apache.

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea style="height: 240px;" name="contenido" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Seleccione una imagen</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
</div>

<button name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
```

```
$user = 1;
$fecha = date('d/m/Y');
$act = 1;

$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ruta = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$destino = '/var/www/html/'.$image;
copy($ruta, $destino);

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
if(!empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['contenido']) && !empty($_POST['image'])){
    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO novedades (userid, imagen, titulo, contenido, fecha, act) VALUES (:us, :img, :tit, :cont, :d, :ac)");
    $add->bindValue(':us', $user);
    $add->bindValue(':img', $destino);
    $add->bindValue(':tit', $_POST['titulo']);
    $add->bindValue(':cont', $_POST['contenido']);
    $add->bindValue(':d', $fecha);
    $add->bindValue(':ac', $act);
    $add->execute();
    header('location: ../');
 } else {
    echo 'Campos incompletos. Vuelva a intentarlo';
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciona perfecto!